# onTouchListener inconsistent when on hold?

Tags: android

I have text field which has an onTouchListener attached to it. When i touch the text, ACTION_DOWN is fired and the text becomes black from its default white. And then I untouch ACTION_UP is fired and the text goes back to white.

However now when I touch and hold the text becomes black and stays like that, I want it so that when i touch and hold it should become black and then white again even while my finger is touching it.

How can I do that!?

I tried using some like this:

```
boolean clicked = true;

    textfield.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        public void onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e){
           if(m.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
             if(clicked){
                // do something
                clicked = false;
             }
           if(m.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                clicked = true;
           }
        }
    }
```

it doesnt work for some reason!!

Comment: can this be done through OnClickListener !?

Comment: Do you want to intercept the "hold" event?

Comment: no, the hold event is irrelevant for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you hold the text, you want it to go black then white (whilst you're still holding it down)?

You could post a delayed message to a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to change the colour x milliseconds after the ACTION_DOWN event. You'll have to manually set the colour rather than rely on the text colour state list as that'll probably interfere with things.